# Batch convert all html files in a directory into pdf files in windows?

Tags: pdf, conversion, batch, html

I see one solution so far:

http://www.htmldoc.org/

Are there any more out there which are suggested?

Comment: HTMLDOC is *the* standard – any reason for not wanting to use it?

Comment: I just didn't know it was "The" standard - so I asked.  But from your answer, I understand that I should not bother with alternatives :)

Comment: I've searched for similar things but – at least on *nix systems, I've always got back to HTMLDOC :)

Comment: @slhck Two reasons - lack of support for unicode and css in the stable 1.8.27 release. However, they are apparently supported in [v1.9b1](http://svn.msweet.org/htmldoc/trunk/) (the notes mention "basic support").

Answer (score 4):

by using http://wkhtmltopdf.org/ you can do it like this:

```
$> wkhtmltopdf http://superuser.com su.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative to **HTMLDOC** is [Prince](http://www.princexml.com/).

*PROs:* Prince can handle most of CSS (which HTMLDOC can't) and use almost all fonts (where HTMLDOC PDFs contain only Helvetica, Times and Courier) and translate HTML/XML input into really well looking pages.

*CONs:* Unlike HTMLDOC, Prince isn't OpenSource software (though free as in beer for private use, putting a rather unobtrusive logo on PDF pages created with it).

PrinceXML is made by a small Australian company and seems to be also driving Google Docs' PDF output.

HTMLDOC is 'good enough' for most people's needs (and also provides quite a few features which Prince doesn't).